# No se muestra el signo "menos ( - )" cuando el valor es negativo en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo 2 fechas en el código, y tengo que calcular el tiempo restante, eso ya lo he hecho, pero cuando este valor es negativo (ya se pasó la fecha), me sigue mostrando el valor sin el signo (-). Eso es un problema porque necesito verificar si este tiempo ya pasó o aún no.

Este es el código usado:

```
// AQUÍ SE LE DA FORMATO A LA FECHA

function format_interval(DateInterval $interval) {
        $result = "";
        if ($interval->y) { $result .= $interval->format("%y years "); }
        if ($interval->m) { $result .= $interval->format("%m months "); }
        if ($interval->d) { $result .= $interval->format("%d days "); }
        if ($interval->h) { $result .= $interval->format("%h hours "); }
        if ($interval->i) { $result .= $interval->format("%i min. "); }
        if ($interval->s) { $result .= $interval->format("%s seconds "); }

        return $result;
    }

    $first_date = new DateTime("$endDate"); // PRIMERA FECHA
    $second_date = new DateTime("$curDate"); //SEGUNDA FECHA

    $difference = $first_date->diff($second_date);
```

Comment: Cuantas respuestas, en cualquier caso puedes mostrar el signo (-) cuando das formato al intervalo con `%r` o `%R` echale un vistazo a la documentación de `DateInterval::format`: http://php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el $difference ya te dice si es negativo o positivo.

Mira esto:

```
$endDate = "2018-05-21";
$curDate = "2018-05-22";
```

un print_r($difference) retorna esto:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 1
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 1
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Sin embargo, si cambiamos las variables para que $endDate sea mayor que $curDate

```
$endDate = "2018-05-23";
$curDate = "2018-05-22";
```

Retorna esto:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 1
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 1
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

La magia está en en [Invert] = 1 o [Invert] = 0

Comment: no conocia el detalle del invert. Me parece muy curioso. Gracias!

Comment: un <pre> y un print_r() siempre son tus mejores aliados al trabajar con arrays/objetos ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como tienes tu código basta con que indique que quieres mostrar el signo, ejemplo:

```
   function format_interval(DateInterval $interval) {
            $result = "";
            // Esta linea añade un menos (-) si la fecha es negativa
            $result .= $interval->format("%r");

            if ($interval->y) { $result .= $interval->format("%y years "); }
            if ($interval->m) { $result .= $interval->format("%m months "); }
            if ($interval->d) { $result .= $interval->format("%d days "); }
            if ($interval->h) { $result .= $interval->format("%h hours "); }
            if ($interval->i) { $result .= $interval->format("%i min. "); }
            if ($interval->s) { $result .= $interval->format("%s seconds "); }
            
            return $result;
        }
    
        $first_date = new DateTime("23-05-2018"); // PRIMERA FECHA
        $second_date = new DateTime("22-05-2018"); //SEGUNDA FECHA
    
        $difference = $first_date->diff($second_date);
        echo format_interval($difference);
        // -1 days
```

Puedes obtener mas informacion sobre los formatos de `DateInterval::format` aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php

Para el caso que nos interesa:

> **%R** |--> Signo "-" cuando es negativo, "+" cuando es positivo
>
> **%r** |--> Signo "-" cuando es negativo, vacío cuando es positivo

Answer (score 0):

Cuando restas dos fechas se aplica esta regla:

```
$objA->diff($objB) == $objB - $objA
```

Una posible solución sería esta (ejemplo):

```
$hoy= new DateTime('2018/5/22');
$fechaVieja= new DateTime('1773/7/4');

$interval = $hoy->diff($fechaVieja);
echo $interval->format('%r%a') . "\n\n";
// -89441

$interval2 = $fechaVieja->diff($hoy);
echo $interval2->format('%r%a');
// 89441
```

Answer (score 0):

También es interesante recalcar que, según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php), a partir de PHP 5.2.2, los objetos DateTime se pueden comparar usando los operadores de comparación.

```
<?php
$fecha1 = new DateTime("now");
$fecha2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

var_dump($fecha1 == $fecha2);  // bool(false)
var_dump($fecha1 < $fecha2);   // bool(true)
var_dump($fecha1 > $fecha2);   // bool(false)
?>
```